# MS Access query using & operators

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am migrating a legacy MS access db to SQL Server, and have encountered a query like :

```
SELECT date1, date2, date3, date4, date1 & date2 & date3 & date4 as FinalDate
FROM tblProcess
```

I need to understand the FinalDate expression.

Basic analysis of data shows that it works like a COALESCE function, but can someone please help with more details?

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator is string concatenation.  I would suggest using the `concat()` function in SQL Server:

```
SELECT date1, date2, date3, date4,
       CONCAT(date1, date2, date3, date4) as FinalDate
FROM tblProcess;
```

`CONCAT()` (unlike `+` which is an operator that can also do string concatenation) will convert its arguments to strings, if necessary.